# How can I get web::Data<Pool<MySql>> in actix-web 2.0 middleware?

Tags: rust, middleware, actix-web

Normally, I can set data on `App` and get the data from `web::Data` like this:

```
let pool = sqlx::MySqlPool::connect("mysql://xxx")
    .await
    .expect("Mysql Connect error!");
HttpServer::new(move || {
    // set the data pool: Pool<MySQL>
    App::new()
        .data(pool.clone())
        .service(web::resource("/home").route(web::get().to(get_xxx)))
})
.bind("0.0.0.0:8000")?
.run()
.await;
```

```
// get the data: pool: Pool<MySQL> from argument.
pub async fn get_xxx(
    pool: web::Data<Pool<MySql>>,
    path: web::Path<String>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let mut pool = pool.clone();
    todo!()
}
```

How can I get the `pool: Pool<MySQL>` in middleware?

This is a sample of middleware:

```
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

use actix_service::{Service, Transform};
use actix_web::dev::{ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse};
use actix_web::{Error, HttpResponse};
use futures::future::{ok, Either, Ready};

pub struct CheckLogin;

impl<S, B> Transform<S> for CheckLogin
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = CheckLoginMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(CheckLoginMiddleware { service })
    }
}
pub struct CheckLoginMiddleware<S> {
    service: S,
}

use actix_web::http::HeaderValue;
impl<S, B> Service for CheckLoginMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Either<S::Future, Ready<Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>>;

    fn poll_ready(&mut self, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.service.poll_ready(cx)
    }

    fn call(&mut self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let pool = todo!(); // here! how can I get the pool: Pool<MySQL>
    }
}
```

I don't know how actix-web passes the arguments to the final route function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [`req.app_data()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/2.0.0/actix_web/dev/struct.ServiceRequest.html#method.app_data) is what you want.

```
fn call(&mut self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
    let pool = req.app_data::<web::Data<Pool<MySql>>>().unwrap();
    // ...
}
```

When you call `App::data()`, actix-web will store the given value into an inner map. The key is its type. When you call `app_data()`, you try to get value from this map.

> I don't know how actix-web passes the arguments to the final route function.

The final route functions just call the `<ParamType as FromRequest>::from_request` to get values. For example, this what happened when you try to get a `web::Data`:

```rust
impl<T: 'static> FromRequest for Data<T> {
    type Config = ();
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Ready<Result<Self, Error>>;

    #[inline]
    fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, _: &mut Payload) -> Self::Future {
        if let Some(st) = req.app_data::<Data<T>>() {
            ok(st.clone())
        } else {
            log::debug!(
                "Failed to construct App-level Data extractor. \
                 Request path: {:?}",
                req.path()
            );
            err(ErrorInternalServerError(
                "App data is not configured, to configure use App::data()",
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that inside `from_request`, `web::Data` gets values (your `web::Data<T>` params) from `req.app_data()`.

By the way, I noticed that you are using `sqlx`, whose `Pool` actually has an `Arc` inside. But `Data` also has an `Arc` inside. It is redundant. If you mind this, you can define a wrapper type of `Pool`, and implement the `FromRequest` trait for it.